# MediaElement - How to get FPS (Frames Per Second)?

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

Is there an way to get FPS of video?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `RenderedFramesPerSecond` + `DroppedFramesPerSecond`. This is the closest you can get to an accurate number with the Silverlight `MediaElement`.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be 100% what you are asking but you can see how fast the video is rendering using the [RenderedFramesPerSecond](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.renderedframespersecond%28VS.95%29.aspx) property of MediaElement. If the computer is keeping up then this should match the FPS of the video.

Answer (score -1):

Not from Silverlight - you have to capture the FPS from the encoding process.