# Get the frame rate (or frames per second) of a MediaElement in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

Simply, I would like to get the frame rate or frames per second of a video in my WPF. In Windows or Linux, this detail can easily be found in Properties, so I'm hoping to reflect this information in my code.

The answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225845/mediaelement-how-to-get-fps-frames-per-second) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550820/can-i-set-the-frames-per-second-of-a-mediaelement-in-c) do not help and also, I do not work with Silverlight. The lines below cannot be recognized in C# WPF.

```
MediaElement1.RenderedFramesPerSecond
MediaElement1.DroppedFramesPerSecond
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most sources on the web say to use this method.  I haven't tried it myself but it could give you a framerate calculation.

```cs
 CompositionTarget.Rendering += (s, a) =>
            {
                ++m_frames;
            };

            DispatcherTimer fpsTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            fpsTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            fpsTimer.Tick += (s, a) =>
            {
                lbl_fps.Content = string.Format("FPS:{0}", m_frames);
                m_frames = 0;
            };
            fpsTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Just a nitpick (nothing serious, really): `++m_frames` is not an atomic operation. Thus, it's perfectly possible that the tick handler sets _m\_frames_ to 0 while `++m_frames` is flying, with `++m_frames` not "seeing" the reset of _m\_frames_ and setting _m\_frames_ back to the previous value+1. Not that it matters much here, as the worst that can happen is that a wrong fps value is briefly shown for a 1s only. In other application scenarios, concurrent manipulation of the same variable/field in a non-atomic unsynchronized way by multiple threads can throw a hard-to-debug spanner in the works.